# Fix invalid JSON String using regular expression, in PHP

Tags: php, json, regex

Following is the json string which got stored in database column in invalid format as .

```
{"id_content": "1"name": "Zappos Case Page 1"id_content_type": "1}


  $variable = '{"id_content": "1"name": "Zappos Case Page 1"id_content_type": "1}';
```

so i want to encode & decode it in php so what will be the regular expression where i can convert the invalid json into valid and parse it properly?

thanks in advance.

Comment: too many mistakes

Comment: validate the json string before saving it to db

Comment: that is my mistake that i haven't validated that before storing into db.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: tried below answers both methods. its working fine for me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is easy to visualize the mistake in your JSON encoding analizing the example provided line. There is a pattern , so it can be recovered easilly.

### REGEX approach

You can fix your string aplying a 2 stages regexp, the first one to introduce the missing double quotes, and the second, to inject the coma delimiters.

```
<?php
$str = '{"id_content": "1"name": "Zappos Case Page 1"id_content_type": "1}';
$str = preg_replace( '/"\w+":\s"[\w\s]*/' , '$0"' , $str);
$str = preg_replace( '/""/' , '","' , $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

### STRING MANIPULATION approach

Another approach is by deconstruction, splitting the string, processing the parts, and building the object again:

```
<?php
$str = '{"id_content": "1"name": "Zappos Case Page 1"id_content_type": "1}';

// remove '{' from the beggining of the string
$str = ltrim($str, '{');
// remove '}' from the end of the string
$str = rtrim($str, '}');
// remove the first '"' from the beggining of the string
$str = ltrim($str, '"');
// split the string in each '"'
$raw = explode('"' , $str);
// prepare an empty array to store valid properties&values
// and store in it the valid keys (removing useless keys ":")
$clean = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($raw); $i++) {
  if ( trim( $raw[$i] ) !== ":") array_push( $clean,$raw[$i] );
}
// asumming property names are on odd keys 
// and values in even keys
// we can now create a valid object...
$obj = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($clean); $i++) {
  if ( $i % 2 === 0) $obj[ $clean[$i] ] = $clean[$i+1];
}
// and convert it back to JSON notation
$jsonObj = json_encode($obj);
echo $jsonObj;
?>
```

---

**INPUT (invalid json):**

'{"id_content": "1"name": "Zappos Case Page 1"id_content_type": "1}'

**OUTPUT (valid json):**

'{"**id_content**":"1","**name**":"Zappos Case Page 1","**id_content_type**":"1"}'

---

**This code will only work, if the pattern is always the same. Otherwise, you will have to addapt the code to the different scenarios.**

Comment: thanks. this works fine. yeah in my scenarios patterns are same.

Comment: i was looking for regular expression. thanks for updating your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can validate the json in JS itself by something like.

```
function isJSON(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

if its valid then send to server side and save into DB.

For existing data, you can not do anything. You might need to do correction manually using any online tool (http://json.parser.online.fr/) before saving to DB.